# How can I select only one column using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to select (and return) one field only from my database with a "where clause". The code is:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only
    @application.route("/user", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def user():
        user_id = session.query(User, User.validation==request.cookies.get("validation")).options(load_only("id"))
        session.commit()
        return user_id
```

This fails and the traceback is:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable
```

How can I select and return just the "id" column? I have tried several other ways too but also with failure. Is "load_only" the correct option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would have to do something along these lines:

```
session.query(Table.col1).filter(User.name=='Name')
```

Comment: thank you for your time. Intuitively that looks like it should work I agree. But error is: TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable

Comment: @user1903663 check my answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63824820/5466534

Answer (score 97):

A [`Query`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) object accepts entities to query as positional arguments, so just pass it `User.id`:

```
user_id = session.query(User.id).\
        filter(User.validation == request.cookies.get("validation")).\
        scalar()
```

[`scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) returns the first element of the first result or None, if no rows were found. It raises MultipleResultsFound exception for multiple rows.

[`load_only()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only) indicates that only the given column-based attributes of an entity should be loaded and all others, expect the identity, will be deferred. If you do need the whole `User` model object later, this can be the way to go. In that case your original query has to change to:

```
user = session.query(User).\
        filter(User.validation == request.cookies.get("validation")).\
        options(load_only("id")).\
        one()
```

[`one()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) returns exactly one result or raises an exception (0 or more than 1 result). If you accept `None` as a valid return value for "no user found", use [`one_or_none()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none).

Note that predicates, the criteria of the WHERE clause, should not be passed to the `Query` object as entities, but added with [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter).

To top it off, views in Flask expect that you return one of:

- a valid response object
- a string
- a `(response, status, headers)` tuple
- a WSGI application

The machinery will treat anything other than a response object, a string or a tuple as a WSGI application. In your original code you returned a `Query` object because of the missing call to `scalar()` or such and this was then treated as a WSGI app.

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid neither of the options you proses works. The first returns error: TypeError: user() takes no arguments (2 given), and the second: TypeError: 'User' object is not callable. I am stuck!

Comment: That is actually a separate error. Your view is expecting you to return a callable of some kind, it seems. I have 0 experience with Flask in general, so you have to consult the documentation for what your view has to return.

Comment: As to how you get `TypeError: user() takes no arguments (2 given)` I cannot say a thing without seeing what you've actually done. It would seem that the view function is passed arguments though it expects none.

Comment: Actually, read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses and especially how it handles anything but a response object, a string or a tuple: "If none of that works, Flask will assume the return value is a valid WSGI application and convert that into a response object.". So I'm guessing your `User.id` is an integer and Flask is trying to treat that as a full blown WSGI application. Try `return str(user_id)`.

Comment: very interesting, thank you! return str(user_id) works. Fascinating insight.

Comment: This explains `TypeError: user() takes no arguments (2 given)` too: you managed to somehow return the view function itself, as it is named `user`. Flask then went on to treat it as WSGI app and passed it `environ` and `start_response`.

Answer (score 31):

**Note:** If you call `Model.query(params)` you would see the following error

```
ERROR: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable
```

You need to call `query(params)` on `session`

*example:*

```
rows = session.query(Model.name).filter(Model.age >= 20).all()
```

**Alternative:**

You can do this using `with_entities`

*example: To fetch names & age where age is greater than 20*

```
rows = Model.query.with_entities(Model.name, Model.age).filter(Model.age >= 20).all()
```

Answer (score 13):

To query the content of one column instead of the entire table flask-sqlalchemy, which I suppose can give you a hint about sqlalchemy itself would work gets you to query the session as you are doing, with a different syntax.

If your table looks something like:

```
class User(...):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

You can query it with:

```
user_ids = session.query(User.id)
all_ids = user_ids.all()
```

This returns a list of all User Ids.

Comment: Just a note that in regular (not flask) sqlalchemy, this returns a list of one-length tuples, which need to be unpacked like [id for id, in session.query(User.id)]

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with queries and db connection. Inside @application.route("/user", methods=['GET', 'POST']) statement you return a user_id which is a result of a select from database. In Flask you should return something [appropriate](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses).

Comment: that is actually true, i replied to the question but looking at the error stack with werkzeug erroring alexey is spot on.