# Sqlalchemy select only one column (syntax > 1.4!)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11530196/14190526) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133774/14190526) questions but they both for old Sqlalchemy version. I'm using the next syntax in my queries:

```
get_user_st = users.select().where(users.c.login == user.phone_number)
connection.execute(statement=get_user_st).fetchone()
```

Here are I selecting by `phone_number`. How I can select a whole column?

Wrong syntax which I already tried:

```
str(users.select(users.c.login))
'SELECT users.id, users.phone_number, users.email, users.login, users.full_name, users.position, users.hashed_password, users.role, users.created_datetime, users.last_update, users.owner_id \nFROM users \nWHERE users.login'

str(users.c.login.select())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/238/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/david/PycharmProjects/na_svyazi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 818, in __getattr__
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/david/PycharmProjects/na_svyazi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'select'
```

I tried to find this case in Sqlalchemy docs but failed.

Getting db:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError


engine_async = create_async_engine(url=config.SQLALCHEMY_ASYNCPG_URL, echo=False, future=True)  # Future -use style 2.0
session_async = sessionmaker(bind=engine_async, autoflush=True, class_=AsyncSession)

async def get_db():
    session = session_async()
    try:
        yield session
        await session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as ex:
        await session.rollback()
        raise ex
    finally:
        await session.close()
```

Type of my session is:

```
type(postgres_session)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.AsyncSession'>
```

P.S. it preferable to not import `select` from `sqlalchemy` but use Table object (`users.c` or just `users`) if it's possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using SQLAlchemy core. rather than using the `select` method of the table instance, use the [select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) function ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#the-select-sql-expression-construct)) or if it is necessary to use the table's method, use [select.with_only_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_only_columns).

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa


engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=True, future=True)
Users = sa.Table('users', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    q = Users.select().with_only_columns(Users.c.id, Users.c.name)
    res = conn.execute(q)
    for row in res:
        print(row)
```

Note that this core behaviour is not new to SQLAlchemy 1.4, although the syntax for `select` has changed slightly.

If you want to query an ORM model class' attributes, the syntax is [similar](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-orm-entities-and-columns), but you access the columns directly

```py
q = sa.select(User.name)
result = session.execute(q)
```

If you want to use an async driver, the code might look like this:

```py
import asyncio

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession

async def async_main():
    engine = create_async_engine(
        "postgresql+asyncpg:///test", echo=True, future=True
    )

    async with engine.connect():

        Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession)
        session = Session()
        # Users is the table from the earlier example
        result = await session.execute(
            Users.select.with_only_columns(Users.c.name)
        )
        print(result.fetchall())

        await session.close()
    await engine.dispose()


asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I before though it's a pretty exact question. This solution isn't applying to me. I updated to question to make it clearer. Particularly my session is doesn't have a `select` method and it's common in my code to use a Table as an object to compose a statement, not a `sa`.

Comment: `sa.select(User.name)`, or passing mapped attributes, is not actually new as such. It has worked pre 1.4/2 as well, so this example would work just the same way. Now as to selecting entire ORM entities...

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Is there a way to make it via `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.AsyncSession'>` object without importing a `select` method from `sqlalchemy` ?

Comment: @salius I've added an async example - does that answer your question?  If not, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @snakecharmerb 1. -It's working, thanks. 2 -I edited a question (added a P.S.), the point is presented also in a comment above

Comment: @salius I think `select.with_only_columns` is what you want then.