# Sqlalchemy asyncio translate postgres query for GROUP_BY clause

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I want to translate the below postgres query into Sqlalchemy asyncio format, but so far, I could only retrieve the first column only, or the whole row at once, while I need only to retrieve only two columns per record:

```sql
SELECT
    table.xml_uri,
    max(table.created_at) AS max_1 
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    table.xml_uri 
ORDER BY
    max_1 DESC;
```

I reach out to the below translation, but this only returns the first column `xml_uri`, while I need both columns. I left the `order_by` clause commented out for now as it generates also the below error when commented in:

Sqlalchemy query:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

query = "%{}%".format(query)
records = await session.execute(
    select(BaseModel.xml_uri, func.max(BaseModel.created_at))
    .order_by(BaseModel.created_at.desc())
    .group_by(BaseModel.xml_uri)
    .filter(BaseModel.xml_uri.like(query))
)

# Get all the records
result = records.scalars().all()
```

Error generated when commenting in `order_by` clause:

> `column "table.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: At first glance this looks ok - are you sure you didn't have `scalar()` instead of `scalars()` in your original code?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, yes, I copied that from the code. so far, I could find a work around from this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809165/sqlalchemy-select-only-one-column-syntax-1-4` and I could retrieve them as a list of dictionaries that I will handle the logic from that point.

Comment: Ah, ok, each row in the resultset is a tuple `(uri, max_date)`, so `scalars` only takes the first element.  Omitting the call `scalars()` should work.

Comment: You can't order by created date, but if you give the max a label you can order by that: `select(M.uri, max(date).label('mymax')).group_by(M.uri).order_by('mymax')`

Comment: @snakecharmerb, Thank you so much. my whole problem was is `scalars()`. but regarding the order, I implemented that out of the query as I might receive desc, or asc from the front-end. If you can please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is returning a resultset consisting of two-element tuples.  `session.scalars()` is taking the first element of each tuple.  Using `session.execute` instead will provide the desired behaviour.

It's not permissable to order by the date field directly as it isn't part of the projection, but you can give the `max` column a label and use that to order.

Here's an example script:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm 

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't73018397'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = sa.Column(sa.String)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Integer)


engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=True, future=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

with Session.begin() as s:
    for i in range(10):
        # Split values based on odd or even
        code = 'AB'[i % 2 == 0]
        s.add(MyModel(code=code, value=i))


with Session() as s:
    q = ( 
        sa.select(MyModel.code, sa.func.max(MyModel.value).label('mv'))
        .group_by(MyModel.code)
        .order_by(sa.text('mv desc'))
    )   
    res = s.execute(q)
    for row in res:
        print(row)
```

which generates this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    t73018397.code, 
    max(t73018397.value) AS mv   
  FROM t73018397 
  GROUP BY t73018397.code 
  ORDER BY mv desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. it solved all problems including the order_by one.